# Cursor backed ExpandableListView data update

Tags: android

I'm implementing CRUD functionality using ExpandableListView. Wen I delete a parent data on screen refreshes automatically but it doesn't when I delete a child. I've solved this with:

```
int categoryId = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
getExpandableListView().collapseGroup(categoryId);
getExpandableListView().expandGroup(categoryId);
```

Is there any better way to this?

Thanks

Aleksander